# sending Uri from activity to another

Tags: java, android

I have this code :

Activity 1

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case FILE_SELECT_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the Uri of the selected file
                Uri fileUri = data.getData();
                Log.d("File", "File Uri: " + fileUri.toString());

                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),activity_file_sharing.class);
                intent.putExtra("Filepath", fileUri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In activity_file_sharing

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("Filepath")) {
        FPath =  Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Filepath").toString());

    }
```

`FPath =  Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("Filepath").toString());`

I am always getting a null reference on the line above , i can't figure out what is the problem

I hope you guys can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it as a `String`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(),activity_file_sharing.class);
                intent.putExtra("Filepath", fileUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Well, the `toString()` in `getIntent().getStringExtra("Filepath").toString()` is redundant.